# How to find the value of this composite function:

Tags: functions, real-numbers

Let $ f,g :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ function such that $ f(x + g(y)) = -x+y+1 $ or each pair of real numbers x and y what is the value of $ g(x+f(y)) $ ?

Please help me with some clue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say $a=g(0)$, then $f(x+a) = -x+1$ for all $x$ so $f(x) = -x+a+1$ for all $x$. So $$-x+y+1 = f(x+g(y)) = -(x+g(y))+a+1$$
for all $x,y$, so $$g(y)=-y+a$$

so $$g(x+f(y)) = -(x+f(y))+a =-x+y-1$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Put $x=-g(y) $ to get $f(0)=g(y)+y+1$. Thus $g(y)=c-y$ for some constant $c$. Given any $t$ take $x=t-g(y)$ in the given equation to get $f(t)=-t+g(y)+y+1$. So $f(t)= d-t$ for some constant $d$. Going back to the given equation you get $c-d=1$. Can  you proceed?